# How do I create a MYSQL trigger that updates stock levels of a product, on update of another table, that has multiple instances of that product?

Tags: mysql, triggers

For a database I'm buildning, I'm trying to make a clothes store.
Among other things, I have two tables, *products* **(P)** , and *product_has_color_has_size* **(PCS)**.

**P** contains information on all the different items in the store, and how many there are left in stock. Stock is based on the sum of total stock in **PCS**.

**PCS** contains further information on each different article, since one article of clothing can have many different sizes and colors.

I'm trying to create a trigger ON UPDATE in **PCS**, where if there's a change in **PCS**, the new TOTAL of stock for that one item, will be set as total in **P**.

So let's say **p**.product_id 3 is represented by three tuples in **pcs**, where the difference is either size and/or color. So 5 blue medium size, 5 red large, 5 white large, would add upp to 15 in stock in table **P**

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_has_color_has_size_updateStock
AFTER UPDATE ON product_has_color_has_size
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    UPDATE products p
    SET p.stock = p.stock + NEW.stock
    WHERE p.id = NEW.product_id;
    
END;
```

This is one of the things I've tried, but either the program doesn't take the unchanged values into account, and only updates with the new value, or it adds old numbers *and* new numbers, and gives me the old stock*2 + new stock.

I hope I've been clear enough, otherwise let me know and I'll try to make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER product_has_color_has_size_{action}Stock
AFTER {action} ON product_has_color_has_size
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE products p
    SET p.stock = ( SELECT SUM(stock)
                    FROM product_has_color_has_size 
                    WHERE product_id = {pseudo}.product_id )
    WHERE p.id = {pseudo}.product_id;
```

`{action}` - INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

`{pseudo}` - `NEW` for INSERT, `OLD` for DELETE, any of them for UPDATE.

Code assumes that only the amount (`stock` value) is changed, the product variation stays unchanged (i.e. UPDATE does not change size/color/etc.).

[modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd3f5dff32924243e8b2b9d49c1d32ef)